# Javascript: Error: Cannot find module '../data/icons/table.png'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, template-literals

I'm trying to pass the path of an image to a child component in react and then provide that path as the source attribute in the child component. When I hardcode the path in the child it works, but when I use template literal it does not.
Below is the code snippet. I am unable to understand why the template literal is not working

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


class MenuItem extends Component{

render(){
    // the below 2 lines print exactly the same thing, i.e., string ../data/icons/table.png
    console.log(typeof `${this.props.icon}`, `${this.props.icon}`);
    console.log(typeof "../data/icons/table.png", "../data/icons/table.png");
    return (
    <div className = "sidemenu menu-item">
        <img src={require("../data/icons/table.png")} />   //this works
        <img src={require(`${this.props.icon}`)} />        //Error: Cannot find module '../data/icons/table.png'.
        {this.props.name}
    </div>
    )
}}
```

Comment: Not the solution, probably, but does `<img src={require(this.props.icon)} />` work?

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I had already tried that, doesen't work ...

Comment: If `this.props.icon` is already a string, why are you wrapping it?

Comment: it is a string, but passed as a prop, in this.props.icon, but as you see in the above comment, `<img src={require(this.props.icon)} />` does not work

Comment: Yes Jared, but this is simply providing the path attribute to the image tag, where is the import actually occuring?

Answer (score 1):

You can load images like modules,  if you are using a bundler (like webpack, or yarn) in the same way that API modules.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import table from './data/icons/table.png';

class MenuItem extends Component{

render(){
    return (
    <div className = "sidemenu menu-item">
        <img src={table} />     
    </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: That's not an ES 6 import, it's a webpack thing. Only works if using webpack (e.g. with create-react-app).

Comment: Also note that while this is preferred where possible, in this case you can't use it (at least not the way you wrote it) because the path to the icon is passed to the constructor as a prop (e.g. it's dynamic).